# DIVs Failing to Align Properly

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align two divs side by side. 
Image on the left, text on the right for first item. 
Text on the left, image on the right second item. 
And finally Image on the left, text on the right third item.

It works properly for the first and third items. The second item fails to align. What have I done wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
padding: 5px;
background-color:#66C;
}

.imageContainer {
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    float: left;
    height: 301px;
    width: 301px;
    background-color:#0CC;
    position:absolute;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.imageContainerRt {
    margin: 0 0 0 0px ;
    float: left;
    height: 301px;
    width: 301px;
    background-color:#0CC;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.text {
    height: 301px;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 0;
    background-color:#C96;
    margin-left:321px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.text2 {
    height: 301px;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 0;
    background-color:#C96;
    margin-right:301px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- First -->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="imageContainer"><img alt="It takes a winning strategy to achieve business success" src="http://market-velocity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/strategy400x400-300x300.jpg" width="300" height="300" /></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h5><span style="color: #66448a;">It takes a winning strategy to achieve business success</span></h5>
      Market-Velocity helps companies map their destination and guides them for a strong competitive advantage.

      The way most companies talk to the market is ineffective. We utilize Strategy Drivers to help your team clearly differentiate you from your competition. We take a close look at what you are saying to your clients and prospects and how your brand affects lead generation and business development.
  <h6><span style="color: #666666;">Strategy Drivers</span></h6>
  <ul class="insideBullet">
    <li><strong>Navigate</strong> – mapping your core identity and differentiation that is compelling to your clients</li>
    <li><strong>Advance</strong> – defining the perception that you want others to have about your company</li>
    <li><strong>Arrive</strong> – developing your messages and fostering the culture of being relentless in your pursuit</li>
  </ul>
      </div>

  <!-- Second -->

    <div class="text2">
      <h5><span style="color: #66448a;">It takes a winning strategy to achieve business success</span></h5>
      Market-Velocity helps companies map their destination and guides them for a strong competitive advantage.

      The way most companies talk to the market is ineffective. We utilize Strategy Drivers to help your team clearly differentiate you from your competition. We take a close look at what you are saying to your clients and prospects and how your brand affects lead generation and business development.
  <h6><span style="color: #666666;">Strategy Drivers</span></h6>
  <ul class="insideBullet">
    <li><strong>Navigate</strong> – mapping your core identity and differentiation that is compelling to your clients</li>
    <li><strong>Advance</strong> – defining the perception that you want others to have about your company</li>
    <li><strong>Arrive</strong> – developing your messages and fostering the culture of being relentless in your pursuit</li>
  </ul></div>
  <div class="imageContainerRt"></div>



  <!-- Third -->

    <div class="imageContainer"><img  alt="It takes a winning strategy to achieve business success" src="http://market-velocity.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/strategy400x400-300x300.jpg" width="300" height="300" /></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h5><span style="color: #66448a;">It takes a winning strategy to achieve business success</span></h5>
      Market-Velocity helps companies map their destination and guides them for a strong competitive advantage.

      The way most companies talk to the market is ineffective. We utilize Strategy Drivers to help your team clearly differentiate you from your competition. We take a close look at what you are saying to your clients and prospects and how your brand affects lead generation and business development.
  <h6><span style="color: #666666;">Strategy Drivers</span></h6>
  <ul class="insideBullet">
    <li><strong>Navigate</strong> – mapping your core identity and differentiation that is compelling to your clients</li>
    <li><strong>Advance</strong> – defining the perception that you want others to have about your company</li>
    <li><strong>Arrive</strong> – developing your messages and fostering the culture of being relentless in your pursuit</li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: Why use an archaic doctype? <!DOCTYPE HTML> Should work just fine.

Comment: Can you please recreate your issue in a JSFiddle so we can see whats happening?  Or even a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.imageContainerRt` should `float:right`, not `left`

```
.imageContainerRt {
    margin: 0 0 0 0px ;
    float: right;
    height: 301px;
    width: 301px;
    background-color:#0CC;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

also make sure to clear your floats with, place this after all your floated containers by adding the class clearfix to the parent container

```
<div class="container clearfix"></div>
```

and add the CSS

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/YAKxk/3/)

Comment: Don't include an empty div just for a clear.  Use a [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) on the parent element instead.

Comment: Looks good in Fiddle. When I copy the code to edit, the second row misbehaves. Seems like an extra image space is after the text. So text, blank space, then image.

Comment: I changed .text2 margin right to 25px and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just add an additional div(as a wrapper) for each row and and the css will be

```
.wrapper{
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code a bit. Removed overhead and wrote it more scalable with sub classes.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Getju

Reasons why it didn't works with your code.
- empty divs
- markup errors
- floating issues (use containers)

If you float elements to each other put them always together in a container - don't float the container.

Floats explained well:
http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Is there a way to keep the text from moving behind the image when the window is resized?

Comment: If you don't have to set the width property in percentage value % - you can go back to Pixels and the problem is gone.

other possibilities are:
- set a min-width of 300px to the imageContainer (but here it's possible that the second row breaks to the next line if there isn't enough space anymore)